# What effect in Unity is Equivalent to After Effects Roughen Edges effect

Tags: unity-game-engine, after-effects

I need an effect in unity that equivalent to the roughen edge effect in After Effects. I looked through but haven't come across anything that comes close.

Comment: reference image/video would be nice :) and would you apply it to whole screen, to single object 2D/3D, UI?

Comment: There isn't an out of the box similar effect. From the description of it, you may get a similar effect by playing with the alpha values in your input textures to the standard shader. But it's up to you to figure out how.